# Bundle - copy-paste gems from another PC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am trying to setup a rails application. The application depends on an enormously huge number of gems. The gems were preinstalled in the `vendor/gems` folder of a copy I obtained from a friend. Now, considering the unavailability of those closed source gems, `bundle install --path /home/umang/projectname/vendor/gems` fails with the message `Could not find gemname in any of the sources`. Is there a way I could copy-paste the gems from the `vendor/gems/` folder into my gem installation directory and make bundle believe that they are there. I copied the directory from `vendor/gems` to my local gem installation directory, but `bundle check` still suggests that those gems are missing.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: This does not only prevent visibility of a perfectly normal question, but also curtails room for improvement of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it is time I answer my own question. 
1. Copy-paste the gems to your gem installation directory.
2. Remove the `.bundle/config` or fix the conflicting setting.