# 'The following gems are missing'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to create a Rails app that can be copied to another hard drive **without having to reinstall its gems**.

One thing I've tried is `bundle install` the gems into `vendor/bundle`, then copy the entire app over to the new location.

At the new location:

```
bundle config set path 'vendor/bundle'
bundle check
# which returns...
The following gems are missing
 * nokogiri (1.10.8)
 * nio4r (2.5.2)
 * websocket-driver (0.7.1)
 * bcrypt (3.1.7)
 * ffi (1.12.2)
 * sassc (2.2.1)
 * pg (1.2.2)
 * puma (4.3.1)
Install missing gems with `bundle install`
```

However, when I go to `vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems`, I see every one of those gems listed.

Try to follow the instruction using the gems in the folder above:

```
bundle install --local
=> Could not find nokogiri-1.10.8 in any of the sources
```

Bundle configuration:

```
~/myapp/.bundle/config:
---
BUNDLE_PATH: "vendor/bundle"
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Either delete or check your bundle config file for conflicting settings and paths that refer to the old location
2. Check for differences between your local and global bundle config files and resolve any conflicts
3. Try reinstalling your gems using the `--local` argument

Sources: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788416/bundle-copy-paste-gems-from-another-pc), [here](https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/issues/4697), and [here](https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/issues/3571)

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your specific question but, a taking a higher view of the issue and recommending a change in approach.

Containerised applications have been created to solve issues like this. Docker is a freely available tool which I recommend you use here.

Here are some links to start you off. It will take a medium investment now of 1-6 hours of playing around but, you'll save time overall. I've been where you are before, since moving to containerised applications I've never looked back

[Docker getting started](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/)

[Docker and Rails](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/)

Comment: I appreciate your comment. In this case, the app is being installed as the only app in that environment so I don't have any need to containerize it.

Comment: The benefit you've described isn't really a benefit of containerisation.

Comment: The main benefit for you of going down the container route here is you'd be able to write your Operating System as code. So you'd have a repeatable, easily configurable entire OS with your App setup and ready to go. You wouldn't have to mess around with issues like you're experiencing here. However, I appreciate that may not be the route you wish to take! Hope you solve your issue pal.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments - I learned something today. :) I will read more about Docker and consider it carefully. Thank you.